# activityIndicator with the web style from docs

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to make an ActivityIndicator like this [image]

In the oficial docs of ActivityIndicator it works like I want for the web, I was trying with animated api but I didn't make it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try make a Lottie animation.
it works to web and react-native

Sources:

> Web: https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/web
>
> React-native: https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/react-native
>
> React-native Lib: https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native
>
> LottieFiles: https://lottiefiles.com/

And, here's a lottie animation wich is kinda simillar with the one you posted:

> https://lottiefiles.com/50-material-loader